# Spring transactionManagers in depdency .jar

Tags: java, spring, transactions, jta

I have 3 transactionManagers configured in my project. We are being forced to use a dependency that uses it's own configured transactionManager, this happens as part of a sub transaction of one of our transactions.

The service class we have to use in this dependency specifies @Transactional, but not which transactionManager to use so Spring goes into it's context and finds all 4 of our transactionManagers (3 in our project, 1 in dependency) and blows up with a NoUniqueBeanDefinitionException.

What would be the fix for this kind of issue?

Comment: if you're using something like Maven for package management, you can `<exclude>` sub-dependencies. so, regarding the lib that you are forced to import… you could import it as usual, but with the proviso that its sub-dependency (transaction manager) be excluded.

Comment: otherwise: you could split this stuff into an external microservice (i.e. make another application entirely). that would give you _different_ problems, but would certainly keep the conflicting transaction manager out of your classpath.

Comment: sounds like what you really want is to modify the `@Transactional` annotation that they specified, and write something else there. i.e. modify the jar that you're forced to import. if you have full source code that's easy. otherwise: it's not beyond the wit of man to replace just one `.class` in a .jar. (.jar is just a zip file, so you can unzip it, disassemble the original .class to source, write your similar, better source, use javac to make a .class and replace the original)

Comment: Unfortunately we are being forced to use the transactionManager in the dependency. I tried enforcing one of my local transactionManagers as the context default with Primary. Unfortunately the dependency's service methods are marked as rollBack and when they error out the whole transaction rolls back instead of just the sub transaction. It does sound like I will have to edit their .jar myself

Comment: Hm, you may not need to _actually_ edit their jar. Just create a clash that has higher precedence. I assume that if you make a class inside your artefact with the same class and package name as theirs: yours would take precedence. Probably it's decided by "who comes first/last on the classpath".